# Equivalent expression to MySql Left Join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, right-join

I'm working on my website and I'm stuck on writing MySQL query which uses "LEFT JOIN" syntax. A simple example of my query is shown bellow:

```
SELECT p.surname, f.f_path as players_image
FROM player p LEFT JOIN file f ON p.id_image = f.id_file
```

The problem is that I'm actually using 8 different tables to get necessary data and I'm joining them after `WHERE` clause(I found it more easier to do that way):

```
SELECT p.surname, f.f_path as players_image
FROM player, file
WHERE p.id_image = f.id_file
```

Can I somehow modify the second queries `WHERE` clause to get the same result as the first query returns?
I know that Oracle DB uses syntax like `WHERE p.id_image(+) = f.id_file` to manage that. It tried that on MySQL data base but it gave me an error.

The original SQL query(table names are different):

```
SELECT sp.id_speletajs, sp.vards, sp.uzvards, ss.numurs, f.f_path as attels, k.id_komanda, p.nosaukums as pozicija
FROM speletajs sp, fails f, speletaja_statistika ss, cempionata_komanda ck, komanda k, cempionats c, sezona s, pozicija p
WHERE
sp.id_attels = f.id_fails
and sp.id_speletajs = ss.id_speletajs
and ss.id_cempionata_komanda = ck.id_cempionata_komanda
and ss.id_pozicija = p.id_pozicija
and ck.id_komanda = k.id_komanda
and ck.id_cempionats = c.id_cempionats
and c.id_sezona = s.id_sezona
and k.mana_komanda = true
and s.nosaukums = (select max(s1.nosaukums) from sezona s1)
```

Comment: Try to find it easier to do it the other way

Comment: Could you give me an simple example how to join three tables(1st  with 2nd by using LEFT JOIN and 2nd with 3rd by using INNER JOIN)? I got the main idea but syntax is unclear for me(how to separate those JOIN parts...)

Comment: Come on; there are 2.5 billion examples out there. Try something.